# Creating django objects from emails

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I want to automatically import emails into my django system.
Lets say I have a model, with fields that correspond to subject,body,from, and possibly others.
How can I set up a system so that any emails to one certain address will will create an instance of such model.

Is there any useful libraries for this, or do I have to write from scratch?

I have a vague idea of something that uses smtplib to connect to some smtp server every 5 or 10 minutes and then gets any new emails and then seperates the fields and uploads them into an object. 
Is this close or is there an easier or better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this app: https://github.com/coddingtonbear/django-mailbox, it looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks, thats very helpful. As some emails have text and html versions, or are just html only, do you have a good solution to figuring which one I should use?

Comment: I don't have much expertise in this area, but AFAIK there is a Content-Type header in emails, you should be able to get it from there.